# not working sort for two characters integer value (for digits that are 10 or more)

Tags: java, android, sorting

I am new to the android programming. I tried to build an app for bubble sort simulation where i will input integers(single or double characters) and get the output of sorted numbers. Here with searching/researching and with the help of others I build this code.

```
public class Simulation extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView Result;
EditText Input;
Button ASButton;

int i,j,temp,num[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ASButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    ASButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BubbleSort();
        }
    });
}

public void BubbleSort() {
    Spannable spn = Input.getText();

    num = new int[spn.length()];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < spn.length(); i++){
        if((spn.charAt(i)+"").matches(".*\\d.*")){

            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+spn.charAt(i));
            count++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
            if (num[i] > num[j]) {
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        result += num[i] + " ";
    }
    Result.setText(result);

  }
}
```

In this code i am getting the result for single characters(0 to 9). but its not working for two or more characters(10 or more). and when i am using 'space' for separating the integers, its showing me some '0's with wrong results. please tell me how to solve this.thank you.

Comment: any reason for sorting by hand in perhaps worst possible way instead of using i.e. `Collection.sort()`?

Comment: `spn.charAt(i)` returns a single character. You need to look at [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) instead.

Comment: split() is saying 'cannot resolve method split()'. and may i know why i got negative vote? i haven't find my solution anywhere that's why I posted my problem here. and its not the duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java). help me if you can.thank you @KenY-N

Comment: `spn.toString().split()`; you need to convert a `Spannable` (which has a `CharSequence` interface) to a `String`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238912/bubble-sort-app-with-user-input-in-android-studio. Asked by same user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are working by character; you need to work with strings.

First, let us assume your input looks like:

```
10 3 5 20 9999
```

The steps needed are: convert to string, split the string into number substrings, then convert the strings to integers. The code (typed out without a compiler) would look something like this:

```
String inputText = Input.getText().toString();

String[] numberStrings = inputText.split(" ");

num = new int[numberStrings.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < numberStrings.length(); i++){
    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberStrings[i]);
}
```

By the way, the Java way to sort is to use `Array.sort(num);`, but I appreciate that you are learning, so doing it explicitly is useful. Furthermore, Insertion Sort is almost always better than Bubble Sort.

Comment: I don't know how would i thank you..this works really perfect..thank you so much @Ken Y-N..and thank you so much Stackoverflow..this is awesome..i promise i will never stop learning prgramming. thank you.